# How can I solve this data logging issue?

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial

I am collecting data through serial communication and below is my code for the same. My plan is that every time the data is received, the data should be logged in a different file with different name (the file name does not matter however, I want it to be different file so I used the time and data module).
But the issue that I am facing is that as soon as the data is received on UART port, the file starts to collect data (I monitor the file size) and after a second or two, the file size goes back to zero bytes. I tried different ways to solve it but I think I am making some silly mistake here which I cannot find.

```
import serial
import time 
import datetime
import os

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0', baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, rtscts=1,)

outputFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                 datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H.%M.%S") + ".txt")

while (True):
    if (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
        text_file = open(outputFilePath, 'w')
        # read the bytes and convert from binary array to ASCII
        data_str = ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode('ascii') 
        # print the incoming string without putting a new-line
        # ('\n') automatically after every print()
        #print(data_str, end='')
        text_file.write(data_str)
        text_file.flush()
 
    text_file.close()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

---

Basically, I have ~900 kB of data that is generated from a microcontroller and transmitted through UART to Raspberry Pi. The data will be sent over to RP several times a day (for ex. 50 times) and each time this 900kB data is sent over, I want to save it in a different file (so 50 files, each with different name and 900 kB of data).
Another thing is I don't have preference saving the file name with data/time. If I can save with something like 1.txt, 2.txt, etc... that is also fine. I won't have access to the RP, so I need this in an automated script.

Answer (score 2):

> ... the file size goes back to zero bytes

Probably because the program is reopening/creating the same file over and over, rather than opening *"a different file with different name"*.
IOW `outputFilePath` has a constant value because its assignment is outside the loop and therefore happens only one time.

---

`text_file.close()` needs to be part of the **if** block, since the `text_file = open()` is only performed conditionally.

---

**Addendum**

> The data will be sent over to RP several times a day (for ex. 50 times) and each time this 900kB data is sent over, I want to save it in a different file

Your simplistic and faulty code apparently presumes that *"this 900kB data is sent over"* as some sort of logical record or block.  As *"every time the data is received"* (as a single record or block), then each record/block *"should be logged in a different file"*.  Of course a *"different file"* requires a *"different name"* (assuming the files will be in same directory).

Your overview of what you want to accomplish did not translate correctly into the required minutia and time scale of computer programming.

*"~900 kB of data"* is not a trivial amount of data for a serial communications link.
The minimum transmission time for that much data at 115200 baud and 8N1 is at least 80 seconds. Your program is not going to be able to read 80 seconds worth of data in one syscall.
The OS (e.g. Linux) has an internal buffer for serial data typically sized at 4096 bytes.  Your one chunk of data would consume 225 buffers.  Your program is not going to be able to read 225 system buffer's worth of data in one syscall.
Instead your posted code is likely to fetch about 100-200 bytes per read, based on the sleep delay and open overhead, and could perform 5000 iterations of the **while** loop for each chunk of data.

IMO your scheme seems flawed.  While time-delimited data chunks can be handled reliably, such a protocol will require significantly more effort and grasp of concepts than you have shown so far.  The lack of a guaranteed time interval between data chunks could be problematic if not due simply to neglect to mention such details.
The transmission of binary data without any apparent integrity checks could be problematic.  The (immediate) conversion to this binary data to ASCII text prior to storage is bizarre if not simply wasteful of time and space.

The risk of receive buffer overrun is high given the (apparent) lack of flow-control.

---

As a basic first step and assist in proof-of-concept, you would probably be best off writing a program to simply capture all data and store it in just one file.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust for pointing that out. However, if I add the `outputFilePath = os.path.join......` either inside while loop (above if loop) or inside if loop (just after if statement), multiple files are being generated. I also had a doubt on if I should use the write mode or append mode. So, I tried append mode, and still same problem. Is there a way around?

Comment: To me, *"every time the data is received, the data should be logged in a **different** file with **different** name"* does mean that *"multiple files are being generated"*. You're complaining that your (redundant) goal is not correct!  You're doing a really poor job of describing your intent. *"... and still same problem."* -- Which symptom are you referring to? BTW the code you posted has only one (1) loop, a **while** loop. An **if** statement is not a loop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question to explain the problem in simpler terms.